# Neo4j Cypher query : Club users likes with friends like

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a neo4j graph which looks like this :

```
  (user)-LIKES->(Actor)
    |              ^
    |              |
  FRIENDS         LIKES
    |              |
    v              |
  (user2)-----------
```

Which states, user friends with user2 and user likes actor and friend (user2) likes actor too.

Now, given actor, when I try to pull all the users friends who like Actor, I do something like  this :

```
START user=node(*)
MATCH (user)-[:FRIENDS]-(friend)-[like_rela:LIKES]-(actor)
WHERE user.uid=123 AND actor.id = 234
RETURN DISTINCT friend, like_rela;
```

The above query returns all my user's friends who like an actor. This does not return the relationship between the user and the actor though. Is there a way I can club this into the same query ?

I am using Neo4j 1.9

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be close to what you are after:

```
MATCH (user {id:123})-[:FRIENDS]-(friend)-[f_like_rel:LIKES]->(actor {id:234})
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[u_rel]-(actor)
RETURN DISTINCT friend, u_rel, f_like_rel;
```

Notes:

1. The above `(user {id:123})-[:FRIENDS]-(friend)` pattern is non-directional, so that the `FRIENDS` relationship can go either way.
2. However, the `(friend)-[f_like_rel:LIKES]->(actor {id:234})` pattern is directional, as I presume you don't want to capture any actors who happen to like your friend (without the feeling being reciprocated).
3. `u_rel` can be of type `FRIENDS` or `LIKES`; or it can be `NULL` if the user has no relationship with the actor. I left this pattern non-directional, but you may want to make it directional.